# Nodejs editor to work on eclipse

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

I have two questions
I just started my learning on nodejs and looking for nodejs editor for debugging and development on eclipse. Is there anything that is available.

I have been working a while on javascript in eclipse, but debugging is poor compared to browser developer console. Its not showing errors at all and jumping from HTML code to JS flow is not happing. Looking for a solution to solve this.

PS: I used to use Aptana Studio and sublime but require something that works with eclipse. Thanks

Comment: just https://www.google.com/search?q=Nodejs+editor+to+work+on+eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is IntelliJ WebStorm which has a lot JS features.. for frontend and also for backend.. Gives you some cool features for debugging like xcode for PHP for nodejs and so on.. It's not free, but it also makes a lot fun, because it's much faster then eclipse (have worked with it a lot.. and the switched) and made for web developers

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's "Visual Studio Code" is a great, free IDE for Node.js.

Check it:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx

Comment: Thank u for the suggestion.